# threejs mixer not updating with `setTime`

Tags: animation, three.js, 3d, gltf

I have a threejs animation mixer set up as follows:

```
this.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(this.object);
this.mixer.timeScale = 2; //play twice as fast
this.mixer.addEventListener('finished', this.handlePullAnimFinished);
this.pullAnim = this.mixer.clipAction(this.animations[0]);
this.pullAnim.clampWhenFinished = true;
this.pullAnim.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce);
this.pullAnim.enable = true;
```

but if I try to do something like `this.mixer.setTime(0.5)`, followed, optionally, by `this.mixer.update()` nothing happens

How do I programmatically set the mixer to a specific point in an animation (and not have it autoplay)?

I've seen the documentation [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Animation-system) on setting up animations to autoplay (and successfully gotten that to work)

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it looks like your mistake is that `.update()` does not have any arguments in it.

[According to the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/animation/AnimationMixer.update), the mixer expects the update method to receive a change in seconds on each frame.

According to [this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=anim#webgl_animation_skinning_morph) you can do something like this:

```
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

function animate() {
    var dt = clock.getDelta();
    mixer.update( dt );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
```

Comment: that's a good callout about mixer update, but I think setTime is supposed to automatically call the update function:

".setTime (timeInSeconds : Number) : AnimationMixer

Sets the global mixer to a specific time and updates the animation accordingly."

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/animation/AnimationMixer

Comment: Keep in mind that performing `.setTime(0.5)` when the `timeScale = 2` will multiply the resulting time to `0.5 * 2 = 1` because "The input parameter will be scaled by the mixer's timeScale." How long is your animation in seconds?

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
// r3f version
useEffect(()=>{
    action.play()
}, [])

useFrame(()=>{
    mixer.setTime(.3)
})

// vanilla version
actions['EmptyAction.001'].play()

let time = .3
animate(){
    mixer.setTime(time)
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
animate()
```

Comment: This looks like react code(?) - If so, I'm not using react.

Comment: @mheavers yes, the point is you should call action.play() once before invoke mixer.setTime

Comment: Thanks a lot, playing the animation once before using setTime did the trick for my problem!